# Direct Sum: Span of Basis Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

We were asked to prove that the direct sum of the Column space of a matrix A, and the null space of the transpose of a matrix A , is R^3.
My solution was to get the basis of both subspaces and show that the basis vectors spanned all of R^3. I am wondering if this makes sense, and if not, why not.

Comment: Consider dim(Col(A)) + dim(Null(A)) = 3. What can you say about dim(Null(A^T))?

Comment: The dimension is the same?

Answer (score 0):

$$\dim(Null(A^T))=3-\dim(\mathcal{C}(A^T))=3-\dim(\mathcal{R}(A))=3-\dim(\mathcal{C}(A))$$ the last equality following from the fact that row rank is same as the column rank of a matrix. Refer [this proof](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-701-algebra-i-fall-2010/study-materials/MIT18_701F10_rrk_crk.pdf)